# how to select blank cells in excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

How do I select blank cells in Office365 excel?

The Go To Special option is not there

[image: The Go To Special option is not there]

When i find blanks in excel application, I use Go To special like this:

[image: like this:]

But when I am using excel 365 I am unable to find blank via Go To, the Special option isn't available there.
Is there any other way to select blanks in online excel?

Comment: There is difference between `Excel For Web` and `Excel For Desktop` --> All Office 365 features are not supported in web version.  You can read here more on the same: **[Differences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6)** --> `Go To Special` is not available in `Excel For Web`